# Why isn't my function pushing the form value to the array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My syntax looks like it's correct. It appears as if the code is working, but, is only showing for a second, then, disappearing. Could someone take a stab at it?
https://codepen.io/Jsiegel003/pen/oNwWmmz

That's my codepen, and, this is my JavaScript code, for anyone who wants to take a quick look.

```
let para = document.querySelector('#Arrays');
let arr1 = [25, 6, 3, 5, 8, 9, 4];
para.innerHTML = arr1;
let form = document.querySelector('#test'); 
let button = document.querySelector('#button1'); 
let para2 = document.querySelector('#Arrays2');

button.addEventListener('click', addValue,  false);

function addValue(Value){
    arr1.innerHTML = arr1 += form.value; }
```

The error that I get from the code results in. Thoughts?

```
{"data":null,"errors":["unexpected"],"success":false}
```

```js
let para = document.querySelector('#Arrays');
let arr1 = [25, 6, 3, 5, 8, 9, 4];
para.innerHTML = arr1;
let form = document.querySelector('#test');
let button = document.querySelector('#button1');
let para2 = document.querySelector('#Arrays2');

button.addEventListener('click', addValue, false);

function addValue(Value) {
  arr1.innerHTML = arr1 += form.value;
}
```

```css
.btn-md {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-md:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.btn-md:active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p id="Arrays">Test</p>
<p id="Arrays2">Test 2</p>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <textarea id="test" placeholder="Enter some comments here">

     </textarea><br>
  <button id="button1" class="btn-md" value="submit">Submit</button>

  <button id="update" class="btn-md">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "pushing the form value to the array" - because you don't actually push it to the array.  Note that buttons default to `type="submit"` so this does that `<button id="update" class="btn-md">Update</button>`

Comment: as does this also `<button id="button1" class="btn-md" value="submit">Submit</button>` - so the function call is done but the submit is also; pretty much at the same time.

Comment: I realize now that I need to use the submit add event listener to the form itself. I used to think that it could be done with a different element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. You are using a form in post mode, which means it will refresh the page and issue a post request. To prevent this, add an onsubmit event handler that calls the event.preventDefault() function to prevent the default submission.
2. You are trying to add the value to the innerHTML of the var arr1, which is not a DOM element. You need to add it to the array, and then set the innerHTML of the DOM element `para` equal to the array.
3. Since we have a form onsubmit handler now, we don't also need to handle the button click.

```js
let para = document.querySelector('#Arrays');
let arr1 = [25, 6, 3, 5, 8, 9, 4];
para.innerHTML = arr1;
let input = document.querySelector('#test'); 
let form = document.querySelector('form');
let button = document.querySelector('#button1'); 
let para2 = document.querySelector('#Arrays2');

function addValue() {
    arr1.push(input.value);
    para.innerHTML = arr1;
}

function onSubmit(e) {
    addValue(input.value)
    e.preventDefault();
}

form.onsubmit = onSubmit;
```

```css
.btn-md{
    background-color: blue; 
    color: white; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    
  }
  
  .btn-md:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white; 
  }
   
  .btn-md:active{
      background-color: red; 
      color: white;
  }
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
 
<head>
</head>

<body>
   <p id="Arrays">Test</p>
  <p id="Arrays2">Test 2</p>
   <form action="#" method="post">
     <textarea id="test" placeholder="Enter some comments here">

     </textarea><br>
     <button id="button1" class="btn-md" value="submit">Submit</button>

     <button id="update" class="btn-md">Update</button>
   </form>

   <script src="Test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: looks like you took that "bad" malformed part of invalid HTML from the codepen  but did capture most of the issues related to the question

Comment: Can you elaborate on this part? I was not aware of any invalid HTML code. I would like to know where specifically it is.

Comment: @user129963 There was a floating </head> tag without a beginning tag. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Oops! If it’s not corrected by now, I’ll fix it. Thank you!

Comment: @user129963 No problem! can you accept this answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

@jbaczuk Describe it very nicely. Just adding to his points. You can clean-up the UI and javascript little such way. So that UI update will be separated from data. Please check the sample code given below.

```js
let values = [25, 6, 3, 5, 8, 9, 4];

// Separate list element, to avoid dirty innnerHTML update
const list = document.querySelector("#list");

const form = document.querySelector("#form");

// proper naming
const input = document.querySelector("#input");

// Update UI based on current values
function updateUI() {
  list.innerHTML = values;
}

// Add value to values, update ui and clean input for another data
function addValue(e) {
  values.push(input.value);
  updateUI();
  input.value = "";
  // Prevent submit
  e.preventDefault()
}


form.addEventListener("submit", addValue, false);

// Initialize for first time
updateUI();
```

```css
.btn-md {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-md:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.btn-md:active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <p>Test: <span id="list"></span></p>

  <form id="form" action="#" method="post" >
    <input id="input" placeholder="Enter some comments here">

    </input><br>
    <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn-md">Submit</button>

    <button id="update" class="btn-md">Update</button>
  </form>
```

```js
let values = [25, 6, 3, 5, 8, 9, 4];

// Separate list element, to avoid dirty innnerHTML update
const list = document.querySelector("#list");

const btnSubmit = document.querySelector("#btnSubmit");
const btnUpdate = document.querySelector("#btnUpdate");

// proper naming
const input = document.querySelector("#input");

// Update UI based on current values
function updateUI() {
  list.innerHTML = values;
}

// Add value to values, update ui and clean input for another data
function addValue(e) {
  values.push(input.value);
  updateUI();
  input.value = "";
  
}

function onUpdate() {
// do something
}
btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", addValue, false);
btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", onUpdate, false);

// Initialize for first time
updateUI();
```

```css
.btn-md {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-md:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.btn-md:active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Test: <span id="list"></span></p>

  <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" >
    <input id="input" placeholder="Enter some comments here">

    </input><br>
    <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn-md">Submit</button>

    <button id="btnUpdate" class="btn-md">Update</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Is the only way that I can do what I want to do is if I use a submit addEventListener with the form? I have updated the form so that it works, basing it off of one of the answers in this forum.

Comment: @user129963, No there are mutiple way. Since you are using form and ajax call, you have to disable submit on button press. Else it will submit form to post. which you don't want. Other way, You can use button to on click, but then you have to disable form on HTML. Let me add sample.

Comment: Check the other example. I have disable from on HTML and handle API call on click.

Comment: Well, the next part of the JavaScript tutorial is going to be about forms, so, I suppose it's sort of a moot point for me to come up with things to say until I watch that tutorial. I guess, that part of the issue, is, that, I have been trying to do something that I have not gotten around to doing yet.

Comment: haha!! yeah.. but that is how javascript works. Try fail and learn